# PHP: Regular expression for replacing space between digits with hard-breaking-space

Tags: php, regex, numbers, space

I would like to create a regular expression that will replace a normal space with hard-breaking space according to my country typographical rules. It shouldn't touch HTML tags.

All spaces in these examples should be hard-breaking:

### Numbers

```
1 000
10 000
100 000
1 000 000
etc..
```

### Dates

```
17. 6.
17. 6. 2012
```

I came up with:

```
$pattern = '/((\d\.?)\s(\d))(?=[^>]*(<|$))/';
$text = preg_replace($pattern, '$2&nbsp;$3', $text);
```

It can do all of these but: 
17. 6. 2012
It won't replace the second space, so result is ->

```
17.&nbsp;6. 2012
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(\d)` is eating the first trailing digit, and if the trailing number only has a single digit, there won't be enough of it left to match on the next pass.

For instance, the following work fine: `12 34 56`, `12. 34. 56`. But these do not: `1 2 3`, `1. 2. 3`

The `(\d)` can be moved into the lookahead, to avoid eating it:

```
$pattern = '/((\d\.?)\s)(?=\d[^>]*(<|$))/';
$text = preg_replace($pattern, '$2&nbsp;$3', $text);
```

Combining this with @flec's use of a lookbehind yields:

```
$pattern = '/(?<=\d)(\.?)\s(?=\d[^>]*(<|$))/';
$text = preg_replace($pattern, '$1&nbsp;', $text);
```

Answer (score 4):

I guess the second space is not matched because the digit in front of it is already consumed by the first match.

I would use a lookbehind instead of matching it, like this:

```
$pattern = '/(?<=\d)(\.?)\s(\d)(?=[^>]*?(<|$))/';
$text = preg_replace($pattern, '$1&nbsp;$2', $text);
```

The dot is outside the lookbehind because the lookbehind must have a specified lenght.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice use of a lookbehind. Helped me understand those and lookaheads a lot better.

Comment: @flec I've just found that your solution doesn't work at some cases: it adds '<' in front of the second number. The Matt Coughlin solution works completely. Nevertheles, thank you both.